# SQL Server installation errors assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to install SQL Server and now I am tired of it. I tried to version SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2. SQL Server 2008 gives the following error (.Net Framework installed)

> Application requires .Net Framework v4.0.30319 AND invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called until the window handle has been created

SQL Server 2008 R2 was giving the following error:

> The following error has occurred:
>
> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl,fileVersion="10.50.1600.1",version="10.0.0.00000",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8002802F.

and after that a new error

> The following error has occurred:
>
> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,version="8.0.50727.4027",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070002.

**EDIT:**

Where in the world can I find .Net Framework v4.0.30319? Its so annoying and confusing.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I had to reinstall OS, which I didnt want to. but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Saddow has written about this issue, and it's more likely a problem with the setup program rather than your OS (though it can't hurt to make sure you've installed all Windows updates too):

- [Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/petersad/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has-been-created)

So instead of installing RTM from RTM media, try slipstreaming with the final service pack for 2008 R2 ([Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271)).

I came across this issue on Windows 7, even when slipstreaming, [but in my case only a reboot was required to get past the issue](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/14/is-sql-server-2008-supported-on-windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2) (simply closing setup and re-launching was not enough).

Peter has also written about slipstreaming:

- [How to slipstream SQL Server 2008 R2 and a SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/petersad/how-to-slipstream-sql-server-2008-r2-and-a-sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-sp1)

That post was about SP1, but you can follow the same basic steps to slipstream a newer service pack.

Comment: check this: `TITLE: SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup
------------------------------

The following error has occurred:

An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl,fileVersion="10.50.1600.1",version="10.0.0.00000",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8002802F.`

Comment: @Qasim so you're trying to install SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2 on an x86 edition of, what, Windows Vista? Windows 7? Why are you forcing yourself to use an x86 OS that old and combining it with such an old version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am using windows 7 Home premium x64. i have tried to install both Server 2008 and 2008 R2 even 2008 R2 service Pack after your recommendation. i have reinstalled .Net Framework 4.0 many time (standalone and web installer both). Sometimes `2908` error occurs and the other time `assembly` error occurs.

Comment: So is your SQL Server media x86? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the following tool which can help figure out what is on your system and has links on where to get any of the .NET Framework versions:

[ASoft .NET Version Detector](http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html)

Also, usually the installation takes care of prerequisites. Maybe you need to either reboot so it is fully installed OR it might be a corrupt install, in which case it needs to be installed again, or repaired.

Also, you can just get the newer Framework versions, such as 4.5.2 or 4.6 and that should be fine as well. But don't worry about the `30319` part of the version, they mean ".NET Framework V4.0".

Comment: it showed that i have .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 framework installed on my PC. While starting the setup it performs some tests and all tests are passed. The only error occurs is about `30319` and after half of the installation, it goes to check installer or something then nothing happens and installation stops.